# Is it possible to inject different service into controller based on if user is logged in or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, forms-authentication, autofac

I am using Autofac as a DI-container in a MVC4 app with forms authentication. I inject services that depend on the a `IContext` in the constructor of the controllers as follows:

```
public MyController(IUserService userService)
{
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

The Autofac `RegisterDependencies` method has the following body:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>()
    .As<IContext>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<UserService>()
    .As<IUserService>;

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

When a user is logged in the `UserService` implementation of `IUserService` is injected. Now I want to have a different implementation of the `IUserService` for not logged in users: `AnonymousService`.

Is there a way to inject the `AnonymousService` via `Autofac` if a user is not logged in and a `UserService` if a user is logged in?

Comment: One option would be to inject a IUserServiceFactory into your code, which at runtime determines whether the user is logged in, and resolves the correct service class.

Comment: @stuartd Sounds like an idea!

Comment: @stuartd On a related note, why should I use an interface to UserServiceFactory if I only have one implementation?

Comment: For mocking in your unit tests

Comment: Ah that's a good point. :-)

Comment: Factories are bad practice, I believe you can use Allows Anonymous attribute in controller to invoke special code for non-logged users instead of change IUserService Implementation based on if user is logged or not.

Comment: @KellermanRivero Factories are a bad practice? To me it sounds like a clean way to do it: have one abstract user manager and have two implementations (one anonymous and one not) where only the methods that are not shared is implemented different. Why is a factory a bad practice?

Comment: In this case you're using DI, the main responsibility for instantiate dependencies is the IoC container. You're creating IUserServiceFactory as the class with the main responsibility for creating IUserService instances, so in the end you're mixing two opposite ideas. that is a bad practice.

Comment: @KellermanRivero Thanks that makes it clear. I will follow the answer of Paolo Costa below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this situation is the perfect candidate for using a keyed service as documented here

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html

You only have two possible implementations for the service, so you just need to define a two values enum:

```
public enum AuthenticatedStatusEnum
{
    Anonymous,
    Authenticated
}
```

and register your service (let's say IUserNameRetriever) twice, once foreach enum value:

```
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserNameRetriever>().Keyed<IUserNameRetriever>(AuthenticatedStatusEnum.Anonymous);
builder.RegisterType<AuthenticatedNameRetriever>().Keyed<IUserNameRetriever>(AuthenticatedStatusEnum.Authenticated);
```

Your controller will be defined in this way:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IUserNameRetriever _currentUserNameRetriever;

    public HomeController(IIndex<AuthenticatedStatusEnum, IUserNameRetriever> userNameRetrievers)
    {
        _currentUserNameRetriever = _userNameRetrievers[AuthenticatedStatus];
    }

    AuthenticatedStatusEnum AuthenticatedStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? AuthenticatedStatus.Authenticated : AuthenticatedStatus.Anonymous;
        }
    }
```

The _currentUserNameRetriever service will have the correct implementation based on the authentication status of the user.

P.S. In a real application you will typically take the AuthenticatedStatus value from another injected service.