# How to use Autofac to inject decorator of a class in one constructor and the class itself in another?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, autofac

I have an `IoCConfig` where in the RegisterDependencies method first all `Services` (same assembly as `ServiceBase`) are registered, except for one service and one class called `LastActivityUpdator` and a decorator of this class called `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` which both implement `ILastActivityUpdator`.

The goals I want to accomplish is to have the decorator registered properly, which already works following [this answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/30902440/dependencyresolutionexception-circular-component-dependency-detected-how-to-use#30909999). And I also asked for a way to for one class (`UserService`) use the `LastActivityUpdator` and for another (`AnonymousUserService`) use the `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator`, which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835744/how-to-use-autofac-to-inject-specific-implementation-in-constructor#30836235). To be complete (I don't think it is relevant to this problem), I am using a keyed service following [this answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/29724069/is-it-possible-to-inject-different-service-into-controller-based-on-if-user-is-l#29725998) to decide which class is injected in other times.

Unfortunately, when I combine the ideas I always see an `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` injected, also in the case of `UserService` where I want a `LastActivityUpdator` to be provided.

Below you'' find the `IocConfig` which uses both the idea to register the decorator and to provide specific classes with one type:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ServiceBase).Assembly)
    .Except<AnonymousUserService>()
    .Except<LastActivityUpdator>()
    .Except<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterType<LastActivityUpdator>()
    .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("lastActivityUpdator");
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()
    .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator");

builder.RegisterDecorator<ILastActivityUpdator>(
    (c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<ILastActivityUpdator>("anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator", 
        TypedParameter.From(inner)),
    fromKey: "lastActivityUpdator")
    .As<ILastActivityUpdator>();

builder.Register(c => new UserService(
    c.Resolve<OogstplannerUnitOfWork>(),
    c.Resolve<CookieProvider>(),
    c.Resolve<ILastActivityUpdator>()));
builder.Register(c => new AnonymousUserService(
    c.Resolve<OogstplannerUnitOfWork>(),
    c.Resolve<CookieProvider>(),
    c.Resolve<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()));

builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserService>()
    .Keyed<IUserService>(AuthenticatedStatus.Anonymous)
    .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<UserService>()
    .Keyed<IUserService>(AuthenticatedStatus.Authenticated)
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Both the `AnonymousUserService` and the `UserService` get an instance of the `LastActivityUpdator`, while I want `AnonymousUserService` to get an instance of the `AnonymousUserService`.

Does anyone know why my RegisterDependencies method does not provide the `LastActivityUpdator` to `UserService` and how I can accomplish this?

**/edit**

Using the answer of Cyril and some adjustments the registering works for the `UserService`, but once the user logs out and a `AnonymousUserService` is used I get the error:

> Circular component dependency detected:
>  Services.AnonymousUserService -> 
> Services.AnonymousUserService -> 
> Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator -> 
> Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator -> System.Object -> 
> Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator

I adjusted the code somewhat of Cyril's answer (fixed some typos and switched the anonymous- and normal UserService) and I might have made a mistake, here it is:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ServiceBase).Assembly)
    .Except<AnonymousUserService>()
    .Except<LastActivityUpdator>()
    .Except<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterType<LastActivityUpdator>()
    .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("lastActivityUpdator");
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()
    .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator");

builder.RegisterDecorator<ILastActivityUpdator>(
    (c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<ILastActivityUpdator>("anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator", 
        TypedParameter.From(inner)),
    fromKey: "lastActivityUpdator")
    .As<ILastActivityUpdator>();

builder.RegisterType<UserService>()
    .Keyed<IUserService>(AuthenticatedStatus.Authenticated)
    .WithParameter(
        (p, c) => p.Name == "lastActivityUpdator", 
        (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ILastActivityUpdator>("lastActivityUpdator"))
    .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserService>()
    .Keyed<IUserService>(AuthenticatedStatus.Anonymous)
    .WithParameter(
        (p, c) => p.Name == "anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator", 
        (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ILastActivityUpdator>("anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator"))
    .InstancePerRequest();

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 kind of registrations for `UserService` and `AnonymousUserService`.

In the first solution you register `AnonymousUserService` by explicitly calling the constructor and by asking *Autofac* to resolve a `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` but there is no registration for this service. Instead of resolving this type, you can resolve a named `ILastActivityUpdator`

```
builder.Register(c => new UserService(
    c.Resolve<OogstplannerUnitOfWork>(),
    c.Resolve<CookieProvider>(),
    c.Resolve<ILastActivityUpdator>()));
builder.Register(c => new AnonymousUserService(
    c.Resolve<OogstplannerUnitOfWork>(),
    c.Resolve<CookieProvider>(),
    c.ResolveNamed<ILastActivityUpdator>("anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator")));
```

The second registration is a `Keyed` but you don't *specify* that the `AnonymousUserService` should use a `anonymousUserLastActivityUpdater` you could do it by using the `WithParameter` method

```
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserService>()
       .Keyed<IUserService>(AuthenticatedStatus.Authenticated)
       .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<UserService>()
       .Keyed<IUserService>(AuthenticatedStatus.Anonymous)
       .WithParameter(
         (pi, c) => pi.Name == "updater", 
         (pi, c) => ResolveNamed<ILastActivityUpdator>("anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator"))
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

You don't have to have both registration, the last one should be enough for your scenario.

Comment: Hi Cyril, thanks again for your answer. We are getting closer: the `UserService` gets the `LastActivityUpdator` injected, but once the `AnonymousUserService` is needed the error `Circular component dependency detected` pops up.  I did make some adjustments to the answer you provided so I might have made a mistake in there. I've updated the answer (under the /edit) and would be very happy if you could take a look

Comment: You should not use the `WithParameter` method for both you registration. By doing so none of your registration used the decorator. 
For the error, do you need to register your types with the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` method ? I recommend you to register all your types manually and don't use assembly scanning and things like that. It will give you full control over your registration. Try to register your types manually and the error message may be more explicit

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work! Working registration registers the `UserService` as follows:

       `builder.Register(c => new UserService(
                c.Resolve<IOogstplannerUnitOfWork>(),
                c.Resolve<ICookieProvider>(),
                c.ResolveNamed<ILastActivityUpdator>("lastActivityUpdator")))
                .As<IUserService>()
                .InstancePerRequest();`. The problem was, I think, that resolving `ILastActivityUpdator` automatically gave an `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator`, this does not happen with ResolveNamed method.Thanks a lot again for your help!

Comment: Also, the `(p, c) => p.Name == "updater"` part cannot be `(p, c) => p.Name == "anonymousUserLastActivityUpdator"`, because when the same name is used as the named registration gives you a `DependencyResolutionException`.